# How can I install Microsoft Office 2010 on a Windows 8 machine?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office

I cannot install Microsoft Office on my Windows 8 machine. When I enter the 25-digit code, it says: `The code is not a Microsoft Office 2013 code`.

How do I proceed? I have a 2010 license, so I would prefer to use that.

Comment: You might have to uninstall the previous version which is Microsoft Office 2013. It might be confusing it with the installed version. Just simply uninstall MS office 2013 and then try installing MS Office 2010 again.

Answer (score 3):

You likely are using the Office 2013 promotional app that I've noticed is preinstalled on new Windows 8 computers lately. You'll have to reinstall Office 2010 yourself.

If you have the install DVDs, just use that.

If you previously downloaded and installed Office 2010 from the Microsoft Store, you simply need to download it again. Go to www.microsoftstore.com and click "Sign In" at the top right of the page. Log in with the account under which you purchased Office 2010. Then on the right side, you'll see a link that says "Downloads, product keys, and subscription". Click that, and it will show you all products you purchased previously. It will show the keys as well as provide download links to install the programs. Simply download Office 2010 again and use your key to register it after installing.